# Making a dot plot with gray dots WITHOUT outlines and color to highlight certain points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to highlight three points on the dot plot in color while the remaining dots are displayed in gray. I almost have it. BUT the gray dots have a black outline that I find distracting. Is there a theme I can use? Or another way to define not just the fill but the outline color of the dots (preferably to match the fill color)?

```
  ggplot(LMPP_0119_SMAD, aes(x = Condition, y = score, fill = newSMAD)) + geom_dotplot(
  binaxis = "y",
  stackdir = "center",
  position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = .2, dodge.width = .4)
) + facet_grid(. ~ IHC) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) + scale_fill_manual(
  breaks = c("1", "4", "14", "0"),
  values = c("grey", "red", "blue", "green")
)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have a more complex graph with 4 separate panels and the black outlines make it difficult to see the color dots.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps take a look at `gghighlight`; it offers functionality similar/identical to what you're after.

Comment: I will check out gghighlight. Looks very promising. Thanks (and wow! so fast).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `color = NA` to the `geom_dotplot()` call.

(You may also want to experiment with the alpha level in the same call, e.g. `alpha = .5`).

Comment: Elegant. I think that is just what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! If this resolves your question, please mark my answer as accepted. (You can click on the check mark besides the answer to fill it in.)